# Do we need a [swift-1.2] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Today, Apple officially released Xcode 6.3 after [exactly two months of beta testing](http://www.macrumors.com/2015/02/09/apple-seeds-first-ios-8-3-beta-to-developers/). With it comes Swift 1.2, a minor update to the language, which includes bug fixes, some compiler improvements, and minor syntax and behavior changes.

These changes, while relatively minor for a new language, have caused [some confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=swift+1.2), to say the least.

[swift1.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift1.2) has already been synonymized to Swift, but these changes can easily break code and aren't necessarily self-explanatory.

Arguably, these could be put under [xcode-6.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xcode-6.3), but I have a feeling that Swift 1.2 might warrant its own tag.

Thoughts?

Comment: Obligatory read [What are the guidelines for using version-specific tags?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/85744)

Comment: @Braiam I think the relevant part to this question would be "The only questions that should use the [tag:c#-4.0] tag, in my opinion, are those questions which are specifically asking for detail about features that were added in 4.0." These aren't just little API diffs; they're actual syntax changes.

Comment: Well, most likely those changes will be kept in the future so "can never be relevant to earlier versions or later versions." should apply. If version X changed bunch of things that will be kept, it would be "pre-X worked, now it doesn't, why?" a better question.

Comment: @Braiam That's fair enough, but it's getting pretty unorganized just throwing them in there with Swift questions; I can see the tag being useful if only just for the transition stage.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

So there was a bit of a kerfluffle about this earlier today. A [swift1.2] tag had been created by a higher-rep user on one of their questions. Another user then [proceeded to mass-edit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1660784/j%C3%A9r%C3%B4me-c?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) that tag into everything that had "Swift" and "1.2" within it. Particularly egregious were [the cases where [swift] was *removed* as a tag in favor of [swift1.2]](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7631022), actually making questions less visible.

This got completely out of hand, so I got to try out [our fancy new ability to temporarily ban editors](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/252991/135615) in order to stop this before it got worse. I then rejected the dozens of outstanding edits that injected this tag. Almost all of the questions with that tag got it because of this one user.

With that context, is this a good tag to have on its own? I'm thinking no, which is why I made [swift1.2] a synonym of [swift].

While Swift is an evolving language, is anyone going to need to have a solution for something in "Swift 1.0" in six months? You'll note that there are no [swift1.0] or [swift1.1] tags in existence on the site. People will just be using Swift. We don't want questions to get lost because someone only tagged them with [swift1.2], which far fewer people will watch than [swift].

Look at what happened with "Objective-C 2.0". Back in 2006, Apple branded all the enhancements they had made to Objective-C that year as "Objective-C 2.0" (properties, fast enumeration, class extensions, etc.). Today, we just refer to that as Objective-C. You don't tag something involving properties as [objective-c2.0], you tag it [objective-c].

Apple likes giving iterative improvements to languages grand-sounding version numbers like this, but they aren't clean breaks in the language and eventually everyone just uses whatever is the latest iteration on the language. Also, if you look at what happened with "Objective-C 2.0", you'll note that Apple stopped giving the language version numbers after that, even though they kept adding features. It's all just "modern Objective-C" now.

There really isn't a compelling reason to refer to an older iteration of one of these languages, so I don't see the need for separate version tags.

Comment: Good points; I just figured I'd ask to find out the reasoning behind it. Swift 1.2 questions are continuing to flood in, and they're all mostly "I upgraded to Swift 1.2 and everything broke. Here are my errors:" I suppose those really don't merit their own tag.

Comment: Counter example: versions of Python. A lot of people want to stick with Python 2.7. Sometimes they stick with even older versions. I haven't seen anyone stick with a specific version of 3... mostly if you're using 3 you're using the latest version of 3 from what I've seen.

Comment: I think is a good rule of thumb that the unversioned tag means "latest available version" and only create versioned tags for obsolete/older ones.

Comment: @Braiam Again, the exception is Python. Many people still use Python 2.7 although Python 3 is out and Python 2 is going to be unsupported in a few years.

Comment: Python 2 was in widespread use for a long time before Python 3 came out. On the other hand, Swift is still in its early and relatively unstable days; the environment and Apple are both pressuring everybody to stay with the latest versions. It might warrant multiple tags in the future, but a lot of growth will come fist.

Comment: @jakekimds well, that might be change in a year when Linux distros change the symlink of python to python3.

Comment: @Braiam That would be a terrifying time for most developers I'm sure (including me).