# Should [swift2] be [swift] too?

Tags: discussion, retag-request, synonym-request

Much along the lines of [this discussion on MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/289859/429427) and [this one on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/85744), can we merge [swift2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift2) into [swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift)?

At the time of writing, there are over 650 questions tagged [swift2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift2), with over 100 in the last week. It seems pointless to differentiate between different versions of the language, especially when it seems a vast majority of the questions don't relate to the specific features of Swift 2 anyway.

### Edit

Something is worth noting in this case that I think makes the Swift tags worth treating differently to other languages that happily use different version tags...

In a matter of months, next to nobody will ever concern themselves with Swift 1.2, and the distinction between Swift 1 and Swift 2 will cease to be. Apple will stop accepting submissions to the App Store that do not use the latest version of Xcode and the Swift language, and so everybody asking questions on SO - even questions directly asking about Swift-2-specific features such as the error handling model - will just tag it [swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift), and won't even think about looking for the [swift2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift2) tag. This will probably leave us with a small, dirty pile of [swift2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift2) questions that will eventually be synonymized or merged anyway.

What's more, judging by Apple's current release cycles, this could well happen every year between June and October. Other languages (such as C++) generally have a new version [every 3-4 years](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B#Standardization), and [older versions continue to be widely used](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/59385) years after a new release. As a small example, 5 questions were asked with the [c++03](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b03) tag this week (4 of them were specifically relevant to that version of the language); I'm not sure people will be using [swift2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift2) in 12 months' time, let alone 12 years' time.

The following quote is from @BradLarson's answer in [the discussion linked above](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/289859/429427), and I think it neatly explains this point of view:

> While Swift is an evolving language, is anyone going to need to have a
>   solution for something in "Swift 1.0" in six months? You'll note that
>   there are no [swift1.0] or [swift1.1] tags in existence on the site.
>   People will just be using Swift. We don't want questions to get lost
>   because someone only tagged them with [swift1.2], which far fewer
>   people will watch than [swift].
>
> Look at what happened with "Objective-C 2.0". Back in 2006, Apple
>   branded all the enhancements they had made to Objective-C that year as
>   "Objective-C 2.0" (properties, fast enumeration, class extensions,
>   etc.). Today, we just refer to that as Objective-C. You don't tag
>   something involving properties as [objective-c2.0], you tag it
>   [objective-c].
>
> Apple likes giving iterative improvements to languages grand-sounding
>   version numbers like this, but they aren't clean breaks in the
>   language and eventually everyone just uses whatever is the latest
>   iteration on the language. Also, if you look at what happened with
>   "Objective-C 2.0", you'll note that Apple stopped giving the language
>   version numbers after that, even though they kept adding features.
>   It's all just "modern Objective-C" now.
>
> There really isn't a compelling reason to refer to an older iteration
>   of one of these languages, so I don't see the need for separate
>   version tags.

Comment: No pun in the title? :(

Comment: @SebastianNegraszus No, I feel the need to help uphold a certain standard of pun on this site, and in this case I have to admit I can't think of a good quality pun beyond "Merge [swift2] [swift]" (which IMHO isn't much of a reward for the reader after they get over the initial distraction of the bad grammar). I'm happy to take suggestions, though! ;)

Comment: This again, *sigh...* why not rename the thing to [apple-swift] and specify that this is The Only Tag™ to be used.

Comment: While we are at it, what about [tag:xcode7-beta2], [tag:xcode7-beta3], [tag:xcode7-beta4], [tag:xcode7-beta5] ?

Comment: The important issue: can we come up with a pun title.  "Can we quickly get rid of [tag:swift2]?"  "Is [tag:swift2] too [tag:swift]?"  So, note that in C++ land, there is the primary tag (of [tag:C++]), and secondary tags for language versions (which are almost always, but not always, used on concert with the primary tag).  This is considered useful, because a [tag:c++] [tag:c++03] question has different answers than a [tag:c++] [tag:c++14] question quite often.

Comment: What about behaviour specific to a certain version? How would define the difference in tags?

Comment: @Yakk Nice, but now you've said that I prefer "Should [swift2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift2) be [swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift) too?".

Comment: the problem is more in the usage of the tag (and tags in general) than in the tag itself. It is relevant to have a tag for specificaly swift-2, as there are significant differences, (like python3 is different from python2, although maybe less) the issue is when people incorretly use the tags. I don't know how to address that.

Comment: @njzk2 I think tag synonyms are "too strong".  Dependent tags, where a tag needs another tag, is right: a post tagged [tag:swift2] should programmatically require a [tag:swift], *or* it should imply [tag:swift] magically.  Both tags are useful for searching, information about the post, etc, but [tag:swift2] by itself is less useful.  The same problem happens in C++ land, and eliminating [tag:c++11] (the equivalent) would be a bad solution.

Comment: Tag hierarchy sounds like a good idea. If "swift2" were considered a child of "swift", and then automagically those posts appeared under "swift", that would solve the problem. There are actually a lot of use cases for this. It seems like tag hierarchy would be a really great idea for SO and SE.

Comment: @oxguy3: We don't have any tag-hierarchy, and that won't change in the foreseeable future. There are quite some FRs requesting them here and on MSE...

Comment: @SebastianNegraszus swifters gonna swift swift swift swift swift.

Comment: I don't see why this cannot be handled as in *all* other major language tags: add a version specific tag. When someone asks a question he either uses only the generic tag or he uses *both* the generic and the version-specific tag.

Comment: @Bakuriu Perhaps because with Swift, old versions of the language will not continue to be used in the way that people still use C++03 today. When a new version is released, everybody is forced to use that new version due to the nature of Apple's control over App Store submissions. The distinction from the old version is forgotten and becomes irrelevant. I've updated the question to address this point.

Comment: I don't know how to solve the problem, but I can see it being useful a year or two from now to have some way to **ignore** language-specific questions which deal with the then-obsolete initial iterations of Swift 1.x

Comment: Pun suggestion: Bring [Swift2] back in time for [Swift]!

Comment: We're up to [2000+ swift questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bswift2%5d%20-%5bswift%5d%20is%3aquestion) now that aren't visible to people searching [tag:swift], many of which have nothing to do with changes between language versions.

Comment: "Should [swift2] be [swift] two?", obviously.

Answer (score 6):

I'll grant that there was some use to separating Swift 2.0-beta questions from Swift questions *while Swift 2.0 was in beta*.

However...

- It's out of beta now. Swift 2.0 shipped with Xcode 7.0 on September 16.
- As others have noted in comments, there's no reason to continue developing in Swift 1.x — Swift 2.0 / Xcode 7 can deploy back to the same target OS versions — and if history is any guide, Apple will soon stop accepting App Store submissions from Xcode 6.x / Swift 1.x.
- Even during the beta timeframe, and continuing now, people have been using [swift2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift2) for version-independent questions about the language or general questions development on Apple platforms. (In fact, looking at the recent questions page for [swift2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift2), I see lots more of these kinds of questions than I see language-version-specific questions.) These questions get lost in a search for [swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift).

I'd say it's time to burninate [swift2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift2) and merge it into [swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift).

I'd also say we should be proactive about catching similar temporary-version-schisms. Swift 2.1 is in beta now (but probably not for long) with very minor language changes, and we can probably expect similar issues when the next Swift version comes along, too. But once those versions are finalized, and long afterward, we don't want any tags created for them to be a graveyard for still-relevant questions either.

Comment: What needs to happen before we can start doing something about [tag:swift2]? The question has been uprooted plenty, but the proposed solutions haven't seen a lot of traffic. In the meantime, the base of iOS/Mac/etc questions continues to fragment into version tags where the version number means nothing, and a few of us continue to manually, tediously, attempt to clean it up...

Comment: Even though the answer for Swift1 & Swift2 is different , I shouldn't add Swift2 tag to this question right? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25921204/convert-swift-string-to-array

Comment: Tags are about questions, not answers. There's nothing *in the question* to do with differences between language versions, so the only language tag on there should be [tag:swift]. You might get answers about Swift 1, 2, or 3.

Comment: BTW, you all have 6 tags about swift.

Answer (score -1):

I see that everyone is sharing their thoughts in the comments. However, I have a few lengthy points so I wish to submit them as an answer.

In my opinion, `Swift2` tag is very useful at the current stage. Most users are still writing their apps in Swift 1.x while certain minority (like myself) are already building new apps with Swift 2.0. Therefore, there is a need to have language-specific discussion.

However, it is also absolutely true that after Swift 2 is released, in less than 6 months there will be no need to have separate tags. With Apple technologies the period between the new technology release and the point when the old one becomes obsolete is extremely short. With other languages/technologies it might be longer, but I think that there is still a problem.

In my view one of the best solutions would be to allow sub tags for certain tags. This way it would be possible to specify `Swift` and then include information about whether this question is related to specific version (`Swift2` for example). In addition, it would be awesome if moderators were able to specify when this sub tag should be used as a separate tag.

For example, currently there could be a rule which said "If a question is tagged as Swift and the version is 2.0 then `Swift2` tag should appear as a separate one". Later, when everyone is working with Swift 2.x it would be possible to change this default behaviour so that specifying Swift + version 2 would no longer create a `Swift2` tag and would just use `Swift` instead.

I also think that if such system was implemented it would be possible to retag all the questions which are currently tagged with `Swift2`. In addition, such system would make it very easy for users to decide which tags to put as they would be specifying just one language and then only the relevant versions of it. At the moment many users don't fully understand whether `Swift2` tag should be used together with `Swift` or not.

Answer (score -1):

Since the compiler for Swift 2 can't (shouldn't?) be used for production code I think we can't merge it with the main swift tag.

If a question is not specific to a version of the language, then I'd say just edit the question to delete the swift2 tag (and mark it as a duplicate if the same question exists for swift 1.x).

Questions that are specific to a version (eg, how do I make this swift 1.2 code work in swift 2?) should be allowed to use the tag.

Once swift 2.0 comes out, any content for an old version of swift should be edited to be up to date with the latest **stable** version of the language. I've already done this with a few of my answers, including one that had to be completely rewritten due to how much arrays have changed.

If somebody asks a question that has already been answered for swift 1.2, but that answer doesn't work on swift 2.0, then they should ask a question "how do I make this swift 1.2 code work on swift 2.0?".