# Shouldn't the Swift X tags be used for specific language changes?

Tags: discussion, tags

Was just going through questions tagged with Swift and again saw multiple with both the Swift and Swift 2 tags. We are now at Swift 2.1 and there is no end in sight to the Apple madness. They made a tool to migrate code which means they probably intend to keep up this way of versioning (and versioning a lot)

A lot of people want to merge Swift 2 into Swift and I agree because of how the tag is used. Which is in duplicate most of the time. But people do have questions about new stuff in each version and then the tag makes sense.

Is it then maybe better to have a tag just for language differences/changes. This would now be 1.2, 2.0 and 2.1 Only questions regarding changes should use these tags. The main Swift tag would then be reserved to clarify that the asker is using Swift and for more general language specific questions.

This is actually closer to how more experienced people use the iOS tags. They use it to ask something about something in an API that worked in one OS version and broke in the next.

Then you would get a collection of Q/A to help people merge from one version of Swift to the other.

Knowing that those answers are there we can ignore the entire "this is a Swift x.x answer/question", if it actually is an API question.

If so maybe we should update the tag info to inform people to only use it for question that directly relate to a change in language and not just to state that they are using Swift x.x and want an answer in that same version. Keeping this up will invalidate a lot of good QA every couple of months.

Comment: You changed your mind about burninate?

Comment: I did. I believe we need better tag info to inspire better use of the SwiftX tags, not less tags.

Comment: Dual-tagging is fine.  Definitely don't merge Swift 2 to Swift, as you'll be throwing away critical meta specifics about the question which help people who get here from Google to easily recognize whether the question may be relevant to them or not.

Comment: FYI, [a merge request was brought up about 7 weeks ago](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/302314/4151918) which suggests that separate versions tags are still needed for now, but will likely go away down the road once we think of the language as "Swift," not "Swift X.0."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to burn the `Swift2` tag as that is critical metadata which people years from now can easily recognize to determine if the (now-older) question is relevant or not.

I don't think it makes sense to burn the `Swift` tag from deprecated or obsolete (old) questions, as **the general tag should represent the language as a whole, not the latest version of the language**.

The language tag isn't meant to be a "filter" for the latest released version, to keep "older" questions out of sight.  People won't be able to reasonably know whether the proposed `Swift` tag would (currently) mean 2.0 or 2.1 or 1.2 when they search.

[swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift) should be the tag for any (general) questions related to the language, just as [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios) has been the main tag for any `iOS` question, **regardless of version**.  If an `iOS` question depends on a new feature, it's tagged with an additional version-specific tag, such as [ios8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios8) or [ios9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios9).

We haven't been retagging old iOS questions, as you can see by the number of questions:

```
    Tags     Number of questions
========     ===================
iOS                      373,578
    iOS9                   1,653
iOS iOS9                     861
    iOS8                  10,085
iOS iOS8                   5,047
    iOS7                  15,038
iOS iOS7                   8,172
```

As you can see, about half of the questions at the time were not tagged with the main tag, but a version-specific tag.  The other half were dual-tagged.

There are always reasons why a developer can't or won't move to the latest version, so the questions being asked may continue to cover 3 versions, such as Swift 1.2, Swift 2.0, or Swift 2.1.

Posters will generally continue to use the `Swift` tag when they have a general question, and likely use a version-specific tag when the question has to do with (a change or new feature in) a specific version.  **This is reasonable and intuitive to people.**

I don't think posters will omit `Swift` from their question when it's not the most recent release, because it naturally is a **Swift** question, regardless of whether it's the previous or current version.

I think if you try to go against the trend and try to force a non-typical convention, you're only going to be creating more frustration and work for yourself, as well as edit reviewers.

Plus, if you burn the **Swift** tag from older questions, I think you actually make it harder for people to find answers, since we can't know or assume which version's answer is the right answer for them.

Comment: I never suggested burning a tag. Unlike many on SO who want to merge Swift2 into Swift. The ios tags serve one purpose. Just stating the os version. The Swift tag at the moment serve 2. They clarify that the code posted/requested is in Swift not obj-c but they also state the version. At the moment this leads to duplicate tags. With Apples trend of pushing multiple version in a year, it would be usefull to have a tag dedicated to migration issues.

Comment: As you probably realize, my answer was prompted by the now-deleted answer by a user that brought up burning/merging tags.  I believe [they want to move that discussion to their own question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/307323/4151918).

Comment: @RMenke As you mentioned, any questions about migration issues would need to be identified by a Swift-version tag, but some will also get tagged as Swift, which is what I believe you want to stop from happening.  I don't think that can be avoided, and I'm not sure we would want to prevent that from happening, as the Swift tag has too much significance as a general language tag.  Trying to reduce it to "all other questions except migration" probably won't work.  You may need to use the **Ignored tags** feature to filter out either the general questions or the migration questions.