# How to tag questions regarding the open source edition of Swift

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

On December 3, 2015, Swift was released as open source project on https://swift.org.
Since then, several [swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift) question were posted 
which refer particularly to this open source edition, and not to the
Swift compiler/runtime that comes with Xcode on OS X.

Some (non-representative) examples:

- [Accessing vscanf etc from Swift Open Source edition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34149529/accessing-vscanf-etc-from-swift-open-source-edition)
- [What type of apps can we create within Linux using Swift (Open Source)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34088335/what-type-of-apps-can-we-create-within-linux-using-swift-open-source)
- [Swift.org issue with open source swift project. Error: xcrun: error: unable to find utility "launch-with-toolchain", not a developer tool or in PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34089153/swift-org-issue-with-open-source-swift-project-error-xcrun-error-unable-to-f)
- [Does Swift 2 provide native sockets? (Not counting stuff from Cocoa etc.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34158182/does-swift-2-provide-native-sockets-not-counting-stuff-from-cocoa-etc)

The questions are less about the core language itself (which hasn't changed
very much from Swift 2.1/Xcode 7.1 yet), but more about the availability
and usage of external frameworks, how to call external functions etc.
Even on the same platform OS X there are differences between these
Swift versions, e.g. how to build a project.

I wonder how these question should be tagged:

- Just [swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift) ?
- [swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift) + [open-source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/open-source)?
- [swift2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift2.2) because that is its current version number?
- [swift-opensource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift-opensource), introducing another Swift tag?

I don't know what the best would be, that's why I am asking here.

Comment: Do we need to worry about this until there's actually branching in the language? Platform tags should be able to handle it. Analogously, we have [gnustep] [objc] [windows] and [cocoa] [objc] [osx].

Comment: @JoshCaswell: From the above examples, the first two could be tagged [swift][linux]. – The third one is about the open source Swift on OS X, and [swift][osx] would not disambiguate it from questions about Xcode's Swift (where the problem does not exist). – The last one applies to open source Swift on all (supported) platforms.

Comment: I said on the previous discussion that [swift] isn't enough... apparently I was ahead of times.

Comment: And please, [let \[open-source\] die already...](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/295218/792066)

Comment: I'm all for [swift.org] or [swift-opensource]. Or anything else *but* we really should be able to separate Xcode's Swift from Swift.org's Swift in the tags. Something like "[swift][osx]" is now very ambiguous about which Swift version the question is about. Being able to do "[swift.org][osx]" or equivalent would be great.

Answer (score 8):

#### Recommendation:

I'd go for adding at least [swift-opensource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift-opensource) or [swift.org](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift.org). (Personally, I favor the former.) Then use the tag wiki/excerpt to clarify that the tag should be used for issues specific to the open source project.

#### Rationale:

Even before open-source, [swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift) was getting used for multiple kinds of questions, and now there are even more:

1. Questions about the language itself or its standard library, and/or questions with another objective where the language is important. (i.e. "How do I do XYZ *in Swift*?")
2. Questions about development for Apple platforms, where the code in the question happens to be in Swift. (i.e. "How do I do XYZ? BTW, I'm using Swift") These are really questions about UIKit or Cocoa or SpriteKit or WatchConnectivity or whatever, so any substantive discussion of them isn't necessarily language-specific.
3. Questions about the open source project itself: e.g. building/installing/using the toolchain, doing compiler-development work, attempting to port it to other OS, etc.
4. Questions about writing Swift programs for Linux (or other platforms where open-source Swift is eventually available)
5. Questions about the "side projects" associated with open-source Swift, like the package manager and the open-source Swift version of Foundation

If you're looking for #2 or #4 questions, you can use tag combinations ([swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift)[ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios), [swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift)[linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linux), etc). If you want #1 or #3 or #5 specifically, it's hard to search without getting a high signal-noise ratio. Adding a tag or two to distinguish the #3 and #5 questions would certainly help.

#### Alternatives:

- As for #1 vs #2 & #4, disambiguating language-specific questions from language-and-target questions is a more general weakness of our tag system — it applies just as well to questions about C++ itself vs questions about developing for platform Foo using C++. This isn't a proposal to fix that (though that'd be a nice thing to fix in general).
- Since Apple's claimed intention is to do further Swift development out in the open, there shouldn't be much divergence in the language itself. (Unless someone forks the project, at which time we can make [the-other-swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/the-other-swift)[no-the-other-other-swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/no-the-other-other-swift) or whatever.) Version-specific Swift tags [are already](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/289859/957768) [causing trouble](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/302314/957768), so we don't really need to fork the tag space around the language itself so much as around the different parts of the Swift ecosystem. (Other languages have it easier here in that the compilers have well-known other names, so you can ask about [clang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clang)[gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gcc)[llvm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/llvm) separately.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your elaborate answer, much appreciated! I also would favor [swift-opensource]. – If some more people express their approval explicitly (as a comment or answer), I would be willing to add tags to affected questions. Until now I am reluctant to do so because I sense some scepticism from the comments and downvotes on the question. Also some more opinions on [swift-opensource] vs [swift.org] would be helpful.